# What are the different types of "flush" that can be done in SilverStripe, and how are they different?

Tags: caching, silverstripe, flush, url-parameters

So I can add URL params to flush the SilverStripe cache and it seems there are at least 2 options:

```
http://example.com?flush=1
http://example.com?flush=all
```

What is the difference between these options, and are there any other options for flushing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flush=1` will flush your current page. Simon Welsh [has said](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/silverstripe-dev/RNWCiFAnRI0/QaUuI35wXUEJ) it will:

- Rebuild the manifests (YAML, statics, classes, templates)
- Flush the current page's templates
- Regenerates images on the current page

`flush=all` will flush every template in the site.

There is a Google group discussion on this topic: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silverstripe-dev/RNWCiFAnRI0

Comment: Looks like the =1 isn't needed... there is a comment in the discussion saying ?flush works the same as ?flush=1

Comment: You're right, `=1` isn't needed for flushing the current page.